# How did Walter and David resolve their disagreement?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

**You should only read this question if you already saw the movie or are not afraid of spoilers. I cannot formulate this question without giving away crucial parts of the plot.**

In the a scene between Walter and David we see that

> they fight, probably until one of them will be dead.

We later know for a fact that

> David survived the battle, as he enters the covenant pretending to be Walter.

The question that comes to my mind is: (sorry, again spoilered)

> Did David kill Walter or convince Walter to let David go, continuing with his experiments?

The motivation for this question comes here:

> During their fight we see that Walter soon controls David on the ground and prepares to land the killing blow but is hesitant to do so. While on the ground David distracts Walter by asking him to choose between them (i.e. humans) or his brother (i.e. androids) while reaching for a knife. The outcome, at least to me, remains unknown. Did David stab Walter, killing or at least disabling him, or did Walter let go?

Comment: Pretty sure the implication is that David stabbed Walter before Walter could deliver the blow. The only reason we don't see it on-screen is because the writers wanted to suddenly "reveal" David at the end, despite the fact that the way they cut away immediately after David reaches for the knife and Walter moves to strike makes the "twist" extremely obvious.

Answer (score -3):

It is a bad plot twist.  Not only is the timeline not enough but they both had different facial scars from the fight.  At no point did the scars change to match David's.  Its more of a like hey, lets throw in this plot twist no one will see coming, because they failed to set it up.

Comment: So how was their disagreement resolved? You seem to have missed that part of the question.